# org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) on project <project-name>: failed to delete directory:

Tags: maven, glassfish

I tried building a java project using maven. I am getting the error "org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) on project : failed to delete directory:" and hence the build is failing. The server is glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many causes for this error. One of the main reasons could be that the directory maven is trying to delete is locked.
Try to access the directory that maven is trying to delete. If you get a prompt like "the file or directory is corrupted or unreadable", try fixing disk errors. It worked for me.
The steps I followed are:

1. Launch CMD on your Windows PC via the Start Menu. Right click on it
   to run it as administrator.
2. Type chkdsk /f x: in the Command Prompt window and press Enter to
   execute the command. X here is the drive letter of the corrupted
   partition that you want to check. Please replace it with your own
   drive letter.